# Problem with navigation in WKWebView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am using `WKWebView` for my WebViewController in my app and I spot one problem with one `URL`
"http://www.viator.com/tours/San-Francisco/San-Francisco-Vista-Grande-Helicopter-Tour/d651-3538VISTAGRANDE?eap=brand-subbrand-75523&aid=vba75523en" there is no navigation through the web site when I tap some other event page nothing happens. Does anyone have any ideas about how to deal with that?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about links opening in a new window, indeed, they don't create a new navigation action. But you can still intercept them, and load the request manually.

If your webview does not have a custom `uiDelegate` already, assign it to your view controller or something else, and then do something like this:

```
extension SomeViewController: WKUIDelegate {

  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
    // Intercept target=_blank links
    guard
      navigationAction.targetFrame == nil,
      let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
        return nil
    }

    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(request)

    return nil
  }
}
```

Comment: I get some UI freezing and after that new page is opened

Comment: That seems to be an issue with that site. Check that same URL in Safari on iOS, and you'll probably see the same freezes.

Comment: it's open new tab

Comment: I had freezes and rendering issues when scrolling after switching back to the initial tab. Try loading a lighter website to validate the code, eg. https://morningreader.com/top